# Pre-populate model value on MVC3 page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP MVC3 and I am trying to make a set of pages for creating and editing sales notes records for customers in our database. On the Customer detail page, I have a table that will display all sales notes for the selected customer and it has a "Create Note" button that goes to a create page for sales notes. How do I pass and pre-populate the CustomerID field on the note with the ID of the customer from the previous page? I searched for an example or tutorial that had this scenario but didn't find one. If you know of a public example a link to it or a direct answer to the question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this fairly easily with routing parameters.  First you need to define the route for the create note action that takes a customer Id.  Next, you need to create the action so that it accepts the parameter.

A quick Google search or "ASP.NET MVC Routing Parameters" turned up this URL which explains it very well:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: Thanks very much! I know it was a very basic questions, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You bet!  Good Luck...MVC is a great framework and fun to use.